# How to add colours to a cell value in Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, colors, kibana, dashboard, elasticsearch-painless

I am trying to create a dashboard using the lens tools in Kibana.I have a requirement to create a dashboard using the data table and within that data table I will have to add some colours to some cells of the data table based on some conditions.
The value of the tables are string type and if the condition is true then the background colour of that cell should be changed to green and if false then green.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMgFn.png)
In the above image you can see that if the value of the cell is compliant then it should be green and if non-compliant than it should be turned red.

Things I Tried already:
1.Add colours to some data field via the Stack Management>Data Views>Add colour - Colours are not getting displayed when add within the dashboard.
2.Tried to use Painless scripting language also to add some conditions but dont know if we can return some colours also or not within that.